# Determining functionality changes from Windows updates

Tags: windows, windows-update

My company maintains a program that uses the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class to monitor a directory for changes. This was working fine until recently. Lately, we noticed that this functionality seems to have changed. It was consistently working on Windows 7 and early Window 10 machines, but on all of our updated Windows 10 machines, the expected behavior has changed.

I am wondering, if anyone knows of a way to apply Windows 10 updates 1 at a time (assuming we have an original Windows 10 machine) so that we are able to narrow down and determine the Windows patch that changed the functionality.

Or, if there are any other suggestions on how else we might narrow down which patch changed specific functionality, they would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Every cumulative patch can be downloaded by itself.  There is a support article dedicated to listing every cumulative patch for both Windows 7/8.1 and Windows 10

Comment: For anyone else looking for this page, it can be found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4018124/windows-10-update-history